# fatal: remote origin already exists - GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm newly at Git. And I tried to create my first repo and push project.

I'm creating step by step to the [Create A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo).

But after I tried to push my project to the empty repo I caught next:

> fatal: remote origin already exists

Here is my ***steps***:

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:nazar-art/NewYearGift.git
git push -u origin master
```

And exactly here I caught this `fatal`.

I tried `git remote -v` to see content of remote repo. Here is result:

```
origin  https://github.com/nazar-art/NewYearGift.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/nazar-art/NewYearGift.git (push)
```

I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like remote origin is already there somehow and you want to change its uri to another value. You can't add origin since its already there but you can update it. Instead of `git remote add` command, you can run:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:nazar-art/NewYearGift.git
```

Comment: Why this happen? Can you recommend any git tutorials?

Comment: @nazar_art Because you didn't actually follow the steps you said.  I imagine you cloned the repository from GitHub with `git clone https://github.com/nazar-art/NewYearGift.git` instead.  There's nothing wrong with that, but in that case you don't need to add a remote because it's been added for you already.  As for tutorials, look [Try Git](http://try.github.io/) and [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/).